# Need an Array Output from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

Chech this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rsLH/) 
for all the running code i am using

i have an array `i=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]`

and i m getting output as

`70:checkbox(checked value 70)`
.

I need all the array to be displayed along with its checkboxes,so that i can check whatever number i want and retrieve the checked ID

desired output:

```
70:checkbox(checked value 70)
60:checkbox(checked value 60)
50:checkbox(checked value 50)
40:checkbox(checked value 40)
30:checkbox(checked value 30)
20:checkbox(checked value 20)
10:checkbox(checked value 10)
```

Code for above Fiddle is here:
 **JS**

```
    var i=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]; 

//$("#add").click(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){

    //  alert("ff");
    var newrow=$('#services .headings').clone().removeClass('headings');
    for(var k=0;k<i.length;k++)

    {
        var disp = {

            names: i[k],
            checks: i[k]

        } 
        func.call(row,disp);
    }

    func(newrow,disp)
    .insertAfter('#services tr.headings')
    .show();
});

function func(row,disp)
{     
    row.find('.servicenames').text(disp.names);
    row.find('.servicecheck').data('href',disp.checks);

    return row;  
}

$("#services").on("click", ".servicecheck",function(){     
    alert($(this).data('href')); 
});
```

**html**

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<table id="services">
                  <tr class="headings"  style="display:none">
                      <td><span class="servicenames"> service names here</span></td>
                      <td><span class="servicecheck" data-href=""><input type="checkbox" id="servicecheck" name="servicecheck"> </td>
                  </tr>

              </table>
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Post your code in your question, don't link to external sources.

Comment: Java **IS NOT** JavaScript.

Comment: expecting results and maximum views so that i can get ASAP

Comment: That's not the way it's done here and it will definitely work against you.

Comment: why -1? my question is not irrelevant or meaningless,am just asking answers from more viewers!!!

Comment: @varunkumar del `i+=1` from `func` and add call `func` into `for`

Comment: I downvoted because of the blatant disregard of the rules. You still haven't posted your code in the question (poor quality) and you knowingly tagged your question wrongly (poor attitude). Votes aren't permanent, fix your post and I'll revert it.

Comment: @Grundy i didnt get the answer,how do u call func?   func.call(row,disp);

Comment: *lol* at ASAP. Also, please consider indenting your code properly.

Comment: next time will surely!!@DaveNewton

Comment: why -2 for this question? i am not able to ask next question guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your jsfiddle you have next code

```
....
var newrow=$('#services .headings').clone().removeClass('headings');
for(var k=0;k<i.length;k++)
{
    var disp = {
        names: i[k],
        checks: i[k]
    } 
}

func(newrow,disp).insertAfter('#services tr.headings').show();

....

function func(row,disp)
{

    row.find('.servicenames').text(disp.names);

    row.find('.servicecheck').data('href',disp.checks);

    i+=1;//this you try change global array, this string need remove
    return row;  

}
```

inside `for` loop you have only declaration `disp`, so you call `func` only once, also you once create new row. for solve this you must change your code like this

```
....
for(var k=0;k<i.length;k++)
{
    var newrow=$('#services .headings').clone().removeClass('headings');
    var disp = {
        names: i[k],
        checks: i[k]
    } 
    func(newrow,disp).insertAfter('#services tr.headings').show();
}

....

function func(row,disp)
{

    row.find('.servicenames').text(disp.names);
    row.find('.servicecheck').data('href',disp.checks);

    return row;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var i=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]; 

//$("#add").click(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){

//  alert("ff");
var newrow=$('#services .headings').clone().removeClass('headings').css("display","block");
for(var k=0;k<i.length;k++)

{
  var disp = {

  names: i[k],
  checks: i[k]

} 

  $('#services tbody').append(func(newrow,disp).html());

}



});


   function func(row,disp)
    {

    row.find('.servicenames').text(disp.names);

    row.find('.servicecheck').data('href',disp.checks);

    return row;  

    }


$("#services").on("click", ".servicecheck",function(){     
    alert($(this).data('href')); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rsLH/1/)

Hope it helps

Comment: that working good,but when checked,the href not working? i mean apart from appending each ('.servicecheck').data('href',disp.checks); can i just append both in a single row

Comment: ur code gives my checkbox in another td of table.that complicates my actual process,since i wll be having atleast 1000 records to be check/uncheck.Thnks for help anywys,above answer was what i planned